# Tight coupling & DI threshold

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have a code that goes like

```
class A
{
    public $b, $c;

    //Inject D and E here? (B $b, C $c, D $d, E $e, ...)
    public function __construct(B $b, C $c)
    {
        $this->b = $b;
        $this->c = $c;
    }

    public function main()
    {
        if (rand(0,1)) {
            new D();
        } else {
            new E();
        }
    }
}
```

Should I inject the possible `D` and `E` classes in constructor of `A`? The problem here is that the hierarchy of the project follows this tree-like structure thus making the upper node `A` to hold all the dependencies of its child nodes. Or is it sane enough to be [stupid](https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/27/Dont-be-STUPID-GRASP-SOLID.html) at some point?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what D and E actually are. If they are just simple data objects you will be fine. If they for example abstract database access, you are better of injecting them.

As a rule of thumb: If you can write a unit test (for example with phpUnit) that works on every system (meaning not just your local dev environment), then the coupling is not that severe and you will be fine with the way you are currently doing it.

If, on the other hand, such a unit test fails due to some missing ressource (e. g. a database connection) one of the dependencies needs, you should inject this service. Then you can create a mock object for the test and it runs again.